# Number of arbitrary constants in an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, constants

Consider the general solution of a differential equation-
$$y=(C_1+C_2)\cos(x+C_3)+C_4\exp(x)+C_5$$
Without differentiating this equation and finding the differential equation for it, how can we say what the order of that DE is. Ofcourse, we can always count the *number* of arbitrary constants, which in this case I think are $4$ (since $C_1+ C_2$ is just *one*). But my textbook says that the DE has order $3$. Am I missing something? I think my mistake is in not absorbing one more constant, which I tried doing in the following way-
$$y=K (\cos C_3 \cos x-\sin C_3 \sin x)+C_4\exp(x)+C_5$$
and then we can also absorb the cosine and sine of $C_3$. But even here, it appears to me that we still have $4$ constants.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $y''''-y'''+y''-y'=0$ Looks like four to me. Typo maybe?

Comment: Yeah, could be possible :(

Comment: lol yeah. I  was thinking maybe $\sin C_3$ and $\cos C_3$ can somehow be written as just one constant and so forth. But that was a really sloppy approach. I guess not right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed rewrite the solution as

$$y=a\cos x+b\sin x+ce^x+d$$ where the four constants are independent. As the functions $\cos x,\sin x,e^x$ and $1$ are linearly independent, the expression does have four DOFs.

---

The terms will be respectively eliminated by the operators $D^2+1,D-1$, and $D$,
giving the equation

$$(D^2+1)(D-1)Dy=0$$

or

$$y''''-y'''+y''-y'=0$$ like said in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

As $C_1+C_2=C_0$, so there are effectively 4 parameters in the solution so its ODE must be of oder $4$.
Let us set up the ODE for
$$y=C_0 \cos(x+C_3)+C_4 e^x+C_5~~~~(1)$$
D. w. r. $x$, then
$$y'=-C_0 \sin(x+C_3)+C_4 e^x \implies e^{-x}y'=-C_0 e^{-x}\sin(x+C_3)+C_4~~~(2)$$
D. w.r. t. $x$
$$-e^{-x}y'+e^{-x}y''=C_0 e^{-x} \sin(x+C_3)-C_0 e^{-x} \cos (x+C_3)$$
$$\implies y''-y'=C_0 \sin(x+C_3)-C_0 \cos(x+C_3)~~~~(3).$$
D. W.R. t. $X$
$$\implies y'''-y''=C_0 \cos(x+C_3)+C_0 \sin (x+C_3)~~~(4)$$
Adding  (3) and (4), we get
$$y'''-y'=2C_0 \sin (x+C_3)~~~~(5)$$
Subtracting (3) and (4) we get
$$y''-y'-y'''+y''=-2C_0 \cos(x+C_3)~~~~(6)$$
D. w. r. t. $x$ in (5), we get
$$y''''-y''=2C_0 \cos (x+C_3)~~~~(7)$$
Adding (6)and  (7) , we successfully get the req\uired fouth degree ODE as:
$$y''''-y'''+y''-y'=0,$$
where all the parameters are eliminated.